# Is it possible to make some animation in vim

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, plugin-system

This issue may be a kind of nonsense but I still want to know if it is possible to make some dynamic stuff in vim 7 or vim 8.

For example, load a file and make if move from left to right (just like https://askubuntu.com/questions/686710/why-do-i-get-a-train-when-i-run-ls).

Comment: This will blow your mind: https://youtu.be/aHm36-na4-4

Comment: @filbranden Very cool animation.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/vim/killersheep